# MySQL query not acting as expected

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all bills that have NOT been FULLY paid.

I have three tables that are needed for this.

Table 1 - billInvoiceMain

```
biId - unique ID
userId - users ID
type - bill or invoice
userItemId - unique ID that user chooses for their records
```

Table 2 - billInvoiceDetail

```
biId - references unique ID in billInvoiceMain
quantity
price
```

Table 3 - transaction

```
transactionId - unique ID
userId - users ID
biId - references id in billInvoiceMain
paymentAmount
```

So a user enters bills, and then once they make a payment (multiple smaller payments could be made on a bill until it reaches the full amount or they could make a single payment for the whole amount) they enter it and it gets saved in the transaction table.

[Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aac65a/1) that has abbreviated versions of test data.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `billInvoiceDetail` (
  `biId` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `productId` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountId` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(20,3) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `billInvoiceDetail` (`biId`, `productId`, `accountId`, `description`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES
(51, NULL, 7, 'Pylaisiella steerei Ando & Higuchi', 4.000, 19.65),
(51, NULL, 11, 'Rubus insons L.H. Bailey', 1.000, 10.17),
(99, NULL, 11, 'Leontodon hispidus L.', 3.000, 11.99),
(99, NULL, 7, 'Peltophorum (T. Vogel) Benth.', 5.000, 33.76),
(100, NULL, 8, 'Scleria P.J. Bergius', 1.000, 10.55),
(100, NULL, 12, 'Gilia ochroleuca M.E. Jones ssp. exilis (A. Gray) A.D. Grant & V.E. Grant', 2.000, 42.54);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `billInvoiceMain` (
  `biId` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(7) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cvId` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `startDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dueDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `userItemId` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `billInvoiceMain` (`biId`, `userId`, `type`, `cvId`, `startDate`, `dueDate`, `userItemId`) VALUES
(51, 1, 'bill', 17, '2021-01-01', '2021-01-31', '53396841'),
(99, 1, 'bill', 28, '2021-01-01', '2021-01-31', '16269083'),
(100, 1, 'bill', 28, '2021-01-07', '2021-01-17', '03200283');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transaction` (
  `transactionId` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `biId` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `paymentDate` date NOT NULL,
  `paymentMethod` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountId` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `paymentAmount` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `transaction` (`transactionId`, `userId`, `biId`, `paymentDate`, `paymentMethod`, `accountId`, `paymentAmount`) VALUES
(51, 1, 51, '2021-01-04', 'Check', 1, 78.60),
(52, 1, 51, '2021-01-19', 'Credit Card', 3, 10.17),
(53, 1, 99, '2021-01-14', 'Check', 1, 10.00);
```

```
SELECT billInvoiceMain.biId, SUM(transaction.paymentAmount), billInvoiceMain.useritemid
FROM billInvoiceMain
INNER JOIN transaction ON billInvoiceMain.biId = transaction.biId
WHERE billInvoiceMain.userId = 1 AND billInvoiceMain.type = 'bill'
GROUP BY billInvoiceMain.biId;

SELECT ROUND(ABS(SUM(billInvoiceDetail.price *billInvoiceDetail.quantity)),2)
FROM billInvoiceDetail
INNER JOIN billInvoiceMain ON billInvoiceDetail.biId = billInvoiceMain.biId
WHERE billInvoiceMain.userId=1 AND billInvoiceMain.type = 'bill'
GROUP BY billInvoiceMain.biId;

SELECT billInvoiceMain.biId, billInvoiceMain.useritemid
FROM billInvoiceMain
INNER JOIN transaction ON billInvoiceMain.biId = transaction.biId
INNER JOIN billInvoiceDetail ON billInvoiceDetail.biId = transaction.biId
WHERE billInvoiceMain.userId = 1 AND billInvoiceMain.type = 'bill'
HAVING SUM(transaction.paymentAmount) != ROUND(ABS(SUM(billInvoiceDetail.price *billInvoiceDetail.quantity)),2);
```

The first query allows me to sum of all the payments from transaction grouped by bill id.

The second query sums all the bills.

The third query I tried combing the two. However, when I try to use a GROUP BY, it gives an error. So, I got rid of that and now it just returns the first bill even if it has been paid.

Desired Results (retrieves the biId and userItemId of all bills that have not been fully paid based on the transaction table):

| biId | userItemId |
| --- | --- |
| 99 | 16269083 |
| 100 | 03200283 |

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out but am lost.

Comment: Always GROUP BY all the non-aggregated columns in the SELECT

Comment: @Strawberry thank you for the comment. However, I am not sure what you mean by that exactly.

Comment: `SELECT billInvoiceMain.biId, SUM(transaction.paymentAmount), billInvoiceMain.useritemid
FROM billInvoiceMain...
GROUP BY billInvoiceMain.biId, billInvoiceMain.useritemid;`

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for explaining. That makes sense. However, I am still confused how that helps with my final goal of needing to be able to select all fully unpaid invoices. Regardless of what is in the GROUP BY in the third query I have, it gives an error.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the desired result

Comment: @Strawberry Just added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query retrieves rows that don't match the `biId` obtained by joining the result of `sum of all the payments from transaction grouped by bill id` and the result of `sum of all the bills from billInvoiceDetail grouped by bill id`.

```sql
SELECT biId, useritemid FROM billInvoiceMain
WHERE userId = 1 AND type = 'bill'
AND biId NOT IN(
  SELECT t.biId FROM
    (SELECT biId,SUM(paymentAmount) pay FROM transaction GROUP BY biId) t
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT biId,ROUND(ABS(SUM(price*quantity)),2) bill FROM billInvoiceDetail GROUP BY biId) d
    ON t.biId=d.biId AND t.pay=d.bill
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aac65a/18)